# How to split QString into floats in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have got next:

```
QString s = "{1.4,3,1.3,33.05}"
```

I would like to split it into floats and write all floats into:

```
vector <Float> v = {1.4,3,1.3,33.05}
```

Do you have any ideas, thanks.

```
vector<float> MainWindow::digits_from_string(QString data) 
{ 
    vector<float> vec; 
    string s = data.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    char *str = new char[s.length()+1]; 
    strcpy(str,s.c_str()); 
    char *pch; 
    pch = strtok(str," ,{}");
    while(pch != NULL)
    { 
    string s; 
    vec.push_back(stof(s(pch)));
    pch = strtok(NULL," ,{}");
    } 
    return vec; 

}
```

I tried this but compiler write that stof() function doesnt exist

Comment: vector<float> MainWindow::digits_from_string(QString data)
{
    vector<float> vec;

    string s = data.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    char *str = new char[s.length()+1];
    strcpy(str,s.c_str());
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(str," ,{}");

    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        string s;
        vec.push_back(stof(s(pch)));
        pch = strtok(NULL," ,{}");
    }
    return vec;
} I tried this but compiler write that stof() function doesnt exist

Comment: @markblacksmith [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46255173/edit) your question and add it there

Comment: This is a strange format; to my eyes it looks like a hybrid between CSV and JSON, yet it's not valid according to either standard. Given the opportunity I'd push back against this format and demand it comply to some sort of known standard formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is your solution :

```
QString data = "{1.4,3,1.3,33.05}";
```

remove `{` & `}` from string:

```
data.remove('{');
data.remove('}');
```

remove spaces :

```
data.remove(' ');
```

separate by `,` :

```
QStringList strList = data.split(QRegExp("[,]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
QVector<float> vector;
```

push them in vector:

```
for(int i=0; i<strList.length(); i++)
{
    vector.push_back(strList[i].toFloat());
}
```

Comment: The last line of your solution can be replaced by the following: `for(QString str: strList) {
  vector.push_back(str.toFloat());
}`,  :P

Comment: Use `mid()` to cut out the first and last char. You don't need a regex for something that simple, a `","` would do.

Comment: @eyllanesc  You meant `foreach` ?

Comment: Qt's foreach is "deprecated", what he means is the C++ range based loop that was introduced in... C++11 was it?

Comment: yes and not, in C++11 there is already the `for(auto element: iterable){}`

Comment: @dtech function `mid()` get index of string, but the size of QString might be change.

Comment: So what if it is changing?

Comment: The same as I said to @Pham, It is correct your code but it is necessary to make verifications but would be dangerous the vector that you obtain, let us say that for some reasons there is no number between the commas, what exit would you have?

Comment: Then because we pray if we can avoid it, for that the function `toFloat()` has an additional verification parameter. The codes that we propose should be the best possible to educate the other members of the community.

Comment: I think you try to make it onerous.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this

```
QString s = "{1.4,  3,   1.3, 33.05}";
QStringList stringList = s.mid(1, s.length() - 2).split(",");
std::vector<float> result;
bool ok;
for(QString item : stringList)
{
    float itemNumber = item.toFloat(&ok);
    if (ok)
    {
        result.push_back(itemNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: Change a new style: `for(QString item, strList) { result.push_back(item.toFloat()); }` :P

Comment: Haha, can. I am compiling with VS2013. I am not sure that new style can work with other compilers. Thanks

Comment: Your code can be correct but also dangerous, if inside the substring there is no numerical data the function `toFloat()` will return zero, I recommend to do a check before saving to the vector.

Comment: for example: `for(QString item, strList) { bool ok; float temp = item.toFloat(&ok); if(ok){result.push_back(temp);} }`

Comment: Agree, just solve that question. Suggest to use json to parse, it is safer.

Comment: Edit your answer because the conversion involves a cost of comparison, and it was not necessary to do it back if you already have the value.